# Which bytecode based language to use when implementation and code size matter?

Tags: programming-languages, bytecode

My requirements are these:

- byte-code Virtual Machine
- C-like syntax
- Small implementation and code size
- Garbage Collection not necessary

Would be used in constrained environments e.g. micro-controllers.

Comment: I think "minor WTF" every time I read a requirement like "x-like syntax". Syntax is syntax - as long as it's not too obscure, it can be read and understood after relatively little time, assuming one knows the language/the underlying semantics (and if not, all is lost anyway ;) ).

Answer (score 0):

The two that come to mind immediately are [Lua](http://www.lua.org/) and [Mono](http://mono-project.com), both of which can be embedded into a program.

- Byte-code VM: Lua and Mono both compile to byte-code.  Mono additionally JITs methods at runtime for better performance.
- C-like syntax: Lua has a C-like syntax and Mono supports many languages, including C#.
- Small implementation and code size: Lua wins here.  Note that Mono can be distributed with a stripped-down version of the framework libraries.  For example, you can throw out the System.Xml assembly if you're not going to be doing XML parsing, etc.
- GC: Both Mono and Lua do support garbage collection.  I'm not sure if this is a pro or a con for your needs.

Comment: To the gc: it is not really needed, so it is neither. Also, mono would be seriously overkill regarding size.

Comment: Ok.  Note that the Mono runtime and corlib are really all you need.  You can get the footprint down to just a few MB.  (Of course, if this is for an embedded device, a few MB is a lot, so I understand why you'd avoid Mono.)